# pandas dataframe, setting index_col to my csv name

Tags: python, csv, pandas, filenames

I have a question in regards to using pd.read_csv
I am currently building a dataframe from multiple csv files from a folder and
the csv files are named as follows: "C2__1979H" or "C2_1999Z"

I would like to set the index of my dataFrame to equal the name of the CSV file it is currently pulling to create my dataframe.
I have yet to find a way to do that. Here is my current code

my dataframe looks like this:

```
    Date     Open    High     Low   Close     Vol  OI  Roll
0   19780106  236.00  237.50  234.50  235.50    0   0     0
1   19780113  235.50  239.00  235.00  238.25    0   0     0
2   19780120  238.00  239.00  234.50  237.00    0   0     0
3   19780127  237.00  238.50  235.50  236.00    0   0     0
```

I want it to look like this

```
            Date       Open    High     Low   Close    Vol  OI  Roll
C2__1979N   19780106  236.00  237.50  234.50  235.50    0   0     0
C2__1979N   19780113  235.50  239.00  235.00  238.25    0   0     0
C2__1979N   19780120  238.00  239.00  234.50  237.00    0   0     0
C2__1979Z   19780127  237.00  238.50  235.50  236.00    0   0     0 ##(assuming this is where the next csv file began)
```

Comment: PLEASE NOTE, I know my index_col = None but I wouldnt know what to put that to anyway, ty

Comment: Just answered to your question, tell me if it fulfills your needs.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to do this? You're abusing the point of the index here, you can either build a dict of dfs, where the key is the csv name or add a field called 'csv_name', by doing what you desire you completely ruin the usefulness of the index

Comment: I am always open to other solutions. Feel free to post an answer below although Romain has done it, I am still open to other ways of doing things. That's how you learn ! TY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does the trick.

```
import os

df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'Close': [235.5, 238.25, 237.0, 236.0],
 'Date': [19780106, 19780113, 19780120, 19780127],
 'High': [237.5, 239.0, 239.0, 238.5],
 'Low': [234.5, 235.0, 234.5, 235.5],
 'OI': [0, 0, 0, 0],
 'Open': [236.0, 235.5, 238.0, 237.0],
 'Roll': [0, 0, 0, 0],
 'Vol': [0, 0, 0, 0]})

df = pd.DataFrame()

# To simulate several df
x=0
for file_ in ['the_path/C2__1979N.csv', 'other_path/C2__1979H.csv']:
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_)
    df_temp['name'] = os.path.basename(filename)
    df = df.append(df_temp.loc[x:x+1,:])
    x+=1

df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df.index.name = None
print(df)

# Result
            Close      Date   High    Low  OI   Open  Roll  Vol
C2__1979N  235.50  19780106  237.5  234.5   0  236.0     0    0
C2__1979N  238.25  19780113  239.0  235.0   0  235.5     0    0
C2__1979H  237.00  19780120  239.0  234.5   0  238.0     0    0
C2__1979H  236.00  19780127  238.5  235.5   0  237.0     0    0
```

In the original code:

```
for file_ in allFiles:
    names = ['Date', 'Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close', 'Vol', 'OI', 'Roll']
    df_temp = pd.read_csv(file_, index_col = None, names = names)
    df_temp['Roll'] = 0
    df_temp.iloc[-2,-1] = 1
    filename, file_extension = os.path.splitext(file_)
    df_temp['name'] = os.path.basename(filename)
    df = df.append(df_temp)

df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
df.set_index('name', inplace=True)
df.index.name = None
df = df[names]

df = df.drop_duplicates('Date') ## remove duplicate rows with same date
```

Comment: what if you dont know the file name? As in, if I ran this code on different folders that within have different # of csv's, different names for csv... then how would the code use that? right now it looks like I would need to type in the name of the file... am I correct?

Comment: When you loop through your files (`allFiles`) you have the filename (`file_`) right ? In this case you have simply to use it. I have typed file names manually just to simulate.

Comment: I have modified my answer to extract only the file name from the path.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the obvious one?

```
df_temp.index = [file_]*len(df_temp)
```